# Does HF react with ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

HF is needed to be dissolved in ethanol in many cases, e.g. in electrochemical etching for fabrication of porous material or in sol-gel synthesis of transition metal oxides being doped with F. Does HF only dissolve in ethanol or can it also react with it to form some fluorocarbon compounds under ambient conditions? If it reacts with ethanol, it will introduce complications in my sol-gel synthesis (ethanol used as solvent and HF as dopant), which I need to take care of.

Comment: HF can't be converted to R-F because HF is a weak acid so it does not react with alcohols.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think HF will react with ethanol under normal conditions. Nucleophilic substitution could be a possibility, but $\ce{F-}$ is worse nucleophile than $\ce{OH-}$, so this won't happen.

Answer (score 2):

If your worried about HF forming fluoroethane, I wouldn't be. HF is for whatever reasons a terrible nucleophile in the liquid phase but a great nucleophile in the gas phase. You should not observe any appreciable reaction, especially when dilute.